# Julia: Writing to file not working as expected

Tags: file-io, julia

I'm trying to write to a file in Julia (0.6.3), but am having some problem.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/networking-and-streams/) the following should work.

```
> f = open("hello.txt","w")
> write(f,"Hello again.")
```

when I `cat hello.txt` the file is blank. That bit of code was taken directly from the documentation. It should work, but does nothing.

I made sure the permissions were okay with `chmod +rw` but that didn't change anything. Both of the following do, however, work as expected.

```
> write("hello.txt","Hello World")

> open("/tmp/t.txt", "w") do f
    write(f, "A, B, C, D\n")
end
```

So when I specify the file directly I can write to it, or if IOStreat, type object is given as part of a `do` it works.

The significance here is that apparently to write to APPEND to a file, as opposed to over write it, you need to use `open("file", "a")`. I could use `do`, however, since I'm learning Julia, I'd like to know WHY something is failing so I can learn from that failure. If I am doing something wrong, I need to know what that is for future reference. If I'm not doing something wrong, than I need to file a bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just below in the documentation:

> If you examine the contents of hello.txt at this point, you will
>   notice that it is empty; nothing has actually been written to disk
>   yet. This is because the IOStream must be closed before the write is
>   actually flushed to disk:

```
julia> close(f)
```

Or as @Bogumił Kamiński wrote in the comment, if you want to flush the data without closing file handler use function [flush/1](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/io-network/#Base.flush).

```
julia> flush(f)
```

Comment: or if you want to keep the file open you can force write the stream with `flush(f)`.